# I have a task to get a list of likes from a Facebook post. Is it possible to use graph-api for this?

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I am writing a desktop application for PC in C#. I'm trying to do it on Graph-API. After authorization oauth2 - there is a token. The method that is documented [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v15.0/object/likes](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

> "https://graph.facebook.com/{object-id}
> ?fields=likes.summary(true)
> &access_token={access-token}"

```
    internal class Get
    {
        public string Response { get; set; }
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
        public Get(string uri)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
                Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    Response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }

Get get = new Get($"https://graph.facebook.com/3475961399339788?fields=likes.summary(true)&access_token={access_token}");
```

Does not work. Returns an error, 400 (Bad Request)

> "(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher"

Tried using the old version v2.3.

> "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{object-id}
> ?fields=likes.summary(true)
> &access_token={access-token}"

Same! Who dealt with Facebook, tell me how to solve this seemingly simple task? Solution with Selenium ChromeDriver - not suitable. It does not allow you to normally get a large list of likes.
I will be glad for any information. Thanks

Comment: That ID redirects me to `https://www.facebook.com/groups/ifyasquintitsmint/posts/3475961399339788/`, so it's a group post. Unless you have admin access to the group, you will only be able to read that if your app gets the Groups API feature approved, and an admin "installs" your app in the group. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/feed#readperms

Comment: I tried any post IDs of people I have as friends. All the same error message. If there was not enough permission, then there would be an appropriate message.